# Преобразование строки в number, начинается с символа

Tags: javascript

Есть строка

```
"!(31310"
```

Как её преобразовать в number?

```
parseInt(), new Number(), valueOf() - не подходят
```

Comment: для начала уберите лишние символы

Comment: В этом и вся суть моего вопроса. Как преобразовать строку если в начале есть символы. Если я уберу лишние символы это уже будет почти готовое решение.

Comment: может ли в строке быть вещественное число ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

например так

```
var string = "!(31310";
var number = +(string.match(/\d+/g));
console.log(typeof number);
console.log(number);
```

что это делает, match собиарет все цифры в массив и склеивает массив с помощью join , а с помощью + мы преобразуем значение с типа String в тип Number

Comment: можно, как минимум, заменить регулярку на `\d+`, и убрать `join`

Comment: возможно, я не особо силён в регулярках :)

Answer (score 1):

для целых чисел решение такое например:

```js
function isNumeric(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}

function getIntFromString(str) {
  var str_num = "";
  var i = 0;
  
  while (i < str.length && !isNumeric(str[i]) 
        && str[i] !== '-')
  { 
    i++;
  }
  
  if (str[i] === '-') {
    str_num += '-';
  }
  
  i = 0;
  while (i < str.length) {
    str_num += isNumeric(str[i]) ? str[i] : '';
    ++i;
  }
  
  return parseInt(str_num);
}

var str = "!(31310";
var num = getIntFromString(str);
alert(typeof num); alert(num);
```